# Select primary_keys that correspond with conditions from another table foreign key

Tags: mysql, select

i have a table with institutions and a table with employees, each employee has a foreign key that points to the primary key for the respective institution. There are men institutions, women institutions and mixed institutions.

I am trying to make a select to display all the institutions where there are at least 2 womens . I can display all the institutions where there are womens but i can't display the institutions where there are at least 2 womens. I used the `idNumber` for selecting the womens as in following code

```
select idInst,nameInst 
from tblInst 
WHERE idInst IN (SELECT idInst 
                 FROM tblEmployees 
                 WHERE idNr>=1999999999999);
```

this will display all the institutions where are women but not all the institutions where are at least 2 womens .
I need to count the womens somehow for each institution but I don't get how to do this .

Comment: And how do you know if an employee is a woman?

Answer (score 0):

With Having clause you can achieve this :

```
select idInst,nameInst 
FROM tblInst 
WHERE idInst IN (SELECT idInst 
             FROM tblEmployees 
             WHERE idNr>=1999999999999
             HAVING count(idInst)  >= 2);
```